# Kubernetes / kubectl print all secrets

Tags: kubernetes, base64, jq, jsonpath, kubectl

I would like to use `kubectl` to print out all key-value pairs in my Secrets. I cannot figure out how to do this in one line with the `-o --jsonpath` flag or by piping into `jq`. I could certainly make a script to do this but I feel there must be a better way, given that the kubernetes GUI is pretty straightforward and liberal when it comes to letting you view Secrets.

Say I create secret like so:

`kubectl create secret generic testsecret --from-literal=key1=val1 --from-literal=key2=val2`

Now I can run `kubectl get secret testsecret -o json` to get something like:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
        "key1": "dmFsMQ==",
        "key2": "dmFsMg=="
    },
    ...
}
```

I can do something like

`kubectl get secret testsecret -o jsonpath='{.data}'`

or

`kubectl get secret testsecret -o json | jq '.data'`

to get my key-value pairs in *non-list* format then I'd have to `base64 --decode` the values.

What is the easiest way to get a clean list of all my key-value pairs? Bonus points for doing this across all Secrets (as opposed to just one specific one, as I did here).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sufficiently recent versions of jq have a filter for decoding base64 but it can only be used if the value that was encoded is a valid JSON string.

Anyway, you could start by trying:

```
.data | map_values(@base64d)
```

Comment: Nice tip regarding `@base64d`

Comment: On Mac OS, `@base64d` [currently requires](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/47) `brew install --HEAD jq`

Comment: thanks @peak and @DomQ
for anyone not familiar with jq, a complete example that worked for me:
`kubectl get secret testsecret -o json | jq '.data' | jq 'map_values(@base64d)'`

Comment: @peak: I think @gongo's point was people not familiar with jq might have trouble invoking this without the complete command. To avoid invoking jq twice you could do `kubectl get secret testsecret -o json | jq -r '.data | map_values(@base64d)'`

Answer (score 19):

I read this question as asking for how to decode *all secrets* in one go.  I built on the accepted answer to produce a one-liner to do this:

```
kubectl get secrets -o json | jq '.items[] | {name: .metadata.name,data: .data|map_values(@base64d)}'
```

This has the added benefit of listing the name of the secret along with the decoded values for readability.

Comment: Modified for just one secret: `kubectl get secret [SECRET NAME] --namespace [NAMESPACE] -o json | jq '{name: .metadata.name,data: .data|map_values(@base64d)}'`

Answer (score 5):

When using the accepted answer you may come across exception

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:96): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

This might be because some json might not be fully formed, use an additional filter

```
kubectl get secrets -o json | jq '.items[] |  select(null != .data) | {name: .metadata.name,data: .data|map_values(@base64d)}'
```

The above will ensure to produce expected results

Answer (score 2):

If you need to extract tls certificates and/or keys from a kubernetes secret and you have an older jq version not supporting map_values(@base64d):

```
kubectl get secrets tls-cert -o json | jq '.data' | cut -d '"' -f 4 | tr -d '{}' | base64 --decode
```

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes get all secretes base64 decode them, and ignore null values.

```
# kubectl get secrets -A -o json | jq '.items[] |  \
select(null != .data) | {name: .metadata.name,data: .data|map_values(@base64d)}' \
> all_secrets_decoded.json
```

Answer (score -1):

For my needs I wrote a shell function, a wrapper around jq, that allows me to filter by names and decode secrets. It doesn't depend on a kubectl version but requires jq in $PATH. It's quite simple in use:

```
divulge() {
    [ -t 0 ] && [ $# -eq 0 ] && {
        echo "\
Discover kubernetes secrets

Usage:
    kubectl get secrets [NAME] -o json | divulge [OPTIONS] [REGEXP]

Options:
  -g  Global search (find all matches, not just the first)
  -i  Case insensitive search
  -m  Multi line mode (. will match newlines)
  -n  Ignore empty matches
  -p  Both s and m modes are enabled
  -s  Single line mode (^ -> \A, $ -> \Z)
  -l  Find longest possible matches
  -x  Extended regex format (ignore whitespace and comments)

  -r  Output raw strings, not JSON texts; values are placed between [ and ]
      and marked with the prefix unsafe, if contain at least a whitespace
  -C  Colorize JSON
  -M  Monochrome JSON

Follow the below link to learn more about REGEXP:
https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Regularexpressions"
        return
    }

    unset DIVULGE_FLAGS DIVULGE_RAW DIVULGE_OPTS

    while getopts ':gimnpslxrCM' arg
    do
        case "$arg" in
        g | i | m | n | p | s | l | x )
            DIVULGE_FLAGS="$DIVULGE_FLAGS$arg" ;;
        r ) DIVULGE_RAW=1 ;;
        C | M ) DIVULGE_OPTS="$DIVULGE_OPTS -$arg" ;;
        * ) echo "Illegal option: -$OPTARG">&2 ; return 1 ;;
        esac
    done

    shift $(( OPTIND-1 ))

    # shellcheck disable=SC2086
    jq $DIVULGE_OPTS \
    --arg regex "$1" \
    --arg flags "$DIVULGE_FLAGS" \
    --arg raw "$DIVULGE_RAW" \
    -r '(.items?[]? // .)
| .data
| select(.)
| with_entries(
    select(
        .key
        | test($regex; $flags)
    )
    | .value |= @base64d
)
| (
    if $raw == ""
    then
        select(. != {})
    else
        to_entries
        | map(
            (
                if .value | test("\\s")
                then
                    "unsafe "
                else
                    "safe   "
                end
            ) + .key + " [" + .value + "]"
        )
        | .[]
    end
)'
}
```

A standalone version can be found by [this link](https://github.com/ildar-shaimordanov/my-scripts/blob/master/shell/k8s/divulge).